# Modifying deeply nested object inside of a BehaviorSubject array

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am building an app in angular. My service `DocumentService` contains a `BehaviorSubject` of an array of Documents.

```
documents: BehaviorSubject<Document[]>
```

Here are the defintions of the classes I have :

```
class Document {
  name: string
  files: File[];
}

class File {
  pages: Page[];
}

class Page {
  data: any;
  scale: number;
}
```

My question is, what is the best way to update the scale property in a page? For this I would have to go down into the document, into the file, and then into the page to modify it. However, I cannot modify it in place since I have to use `this.documents.next(newDocumentsArray)`. Problem is, deep copying doesn't work - `JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(...))` gives me a circular structure error, while the other ways (`.map`, `Object.assign`, ...) only give me shallow copies that then modify the page in place, which is something that we can't do.

Any tips? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you wish to keep your current deep structure, you'd need to drill down:

```js
const newDocs = oldDocs.map(doc => {
  if (doc !== docToChange) {
    return doc;
  } else {
    return {
      ...doc,
      files: doc.files.map(file => ({
        ...file,
        pages: file.pages.map(page => {
          // do page change here
        })
      }))
    };
  }
});
```

I'd suggest a switch to a flat Entity-like structure, where all Documents, Files, and Pages are stored by unique ID in separate dictionaries, and a Document's `files` array contains the ids of its Files, with the same for Files referring to their Pages. Does that make sense?

Comment: Thank you for the helpful reply. I will consider flattening my structure.